# Programmatically added subview doesn't interact with other views, but xib-added view worked fine

Tags: ios, uiview, touch, touchesmoved

harlanhaskins wrote:

I have a view called userSlider programmaticaly added in viewDidLoad:

```
 self.userSlider = [[UserSliderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -120, 320, 155)];
     [self.userSlider setUser:user];
     [self.userSlider configureView];
     [self.view addSubview:self.userSlider];
```

And a tableview called gameTableView.

I originally had added the userSlider into the xib as a custom view (because UserSlider has its own xib), and when I implemented these touch methods:

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = (UITouch*)[touches anyObject];

start = [touch locationInView:self.view].y;
 }



 -(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

if(start < 0)

{

    return;

}

UITouch *touch = (UITouch *)[touches anyObject];

CGFloat now = [touch locationInView:self.view].y;

CGFloat diff = now - start;

sliderDirectionIsUp = diff < 0; //sliderDirectionIsUp is a BOOL

if ((self.userSlider.frame.origin.y == 0) && ((now < 120) || (now > 155))) {

    return;

}

float newCenterY = self.userSlider.center.y + diff;

if (newCenterY < roundf(self.userSlider.frame.size.height / 2)) {

    self.userSlider.center = CGPointMake(self.userSlider.center.x, newCenterY);

    CGRect tableViewFrame = self.gameTableView.frame;

    tableViewFrame.origin.y += diff;

    tableViewFrame.size.height -= diff;

    [self.gameTableView setFrame:tableViewFrame];

}

start = now;

 }



 -(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

 {

CGRect tableViewFrame = self.gameTableView.frame;

if (sliderDirectionIsUp)

{

    tableViewFrame.origin.y = 28;

    tableViewFrame.size.height = (self.view.frame.size.height - tableViewFrame.origin.y);

    //animate userSlider out of visible area

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{

        self.userSlider.center = CGPointMake(self.userSlider.center.x, -roundf(self.userSlider.bounds.size.height/2.) + 35);

        [self.gameTableView setFrame:tableViewFrame];

    }];

}

else if(start >= 0)

{

    tableViewFrame.origin.y = (self.userSlider.frame.size.height - 7);

    tableViewFrame.size.height = (self.view.frame.size.height - tableViewFrame.origin.y);

    //animate userSlider with top to mainviews top

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{

        self.userSlider.center = CGPointMake(self.userSlider.center.x, roundf(self.userSlider.bounds.size.height/2.) - 0.5);

        [self.gameTableView setFrame:tableViewFrame];

    }];

}

 }
```

then both views would move how I wanted them to.

But now when I add it programmatically, suddenly the tableView doesn't change unless I tap inside the area after moving it. It's really weird.

Any ideas?

Comment: what happens if you move those 4 lines of code in viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear?

Comment: Nothing. Funny, though, that when the view doesn't get added as a subview, the tableView adjusts fine...

Answer (score 0):

If your userSlider`s frame is

```
CGRectMake(0, -120, 320, 155)
```

I doubt whether your userSlider can receive the sender event .Because if a UIControl`s frame  be out of the superView , it may not receive the sender event(the outside part) . You can set the frame

```
CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 155)
```

to have a try .

Comment: It gets the events fine, and the userSlider moves with my taps just like I want it to. But the tableView doesn't move unless I tap between 120 and 155 _after_ it's been pulled down...

Comment: @HarlanHaskins you want the table to move only if its tapped between 120 and 155 right?

Comment: Lemme explain a bit further.

http://imgur.com/a/OkeSh

The View is hidden from (relative to itself) from 0 to 120 (vertically). When you pull it down, it just moves the center. It's also supposed to adjust the size and origin of the tableView.